# can't use pony orm on sqlite3 blob fields

Tags: python, sqlite, ponyorm

Just trying some basic exercises with pony ORM (and python3.5, sqlite3).
I just want to print a select query of some data I have without further processing to start with. Pony orm does not seem to like that at all....

The sqlite db dump

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE sums (t text, path BLOB, name BLOB, sum text, primary key (path,name));
INSERT INTO "sums" VALUES('directory','','','');
INSERT INTO "sums" VALUES('file','','sums-backup-f.db','6859b35f9f026317c5df48932f9f2a91');
INSERT INTO "sums" VALUES('file','','md5-tree.py','c7af81d4aad9d00e88db7af950c264c2');
INSERT INTO "sums" VALUES('file','','test.db','a403e9b46e54d6ece851881a895b1953');
INSERT INTO "sums" VALUES('file','','sirius-alexa.db','22a20434cec550a83c675acd849002fa');
INSERT INTO "sums" VALUES('file','','sums-reseau-y.db','1021614f692b5d7bdeef2a45b6b1af5b');
INSERT INTO "sums" VALUES('file','','.md5-tree.py.swp','1c3c195b679e99ef18b3d46044f6e6c5');
INSERT INTO "sums" VALUES('file','','compare-md5.py','cfb4a5b3c7c4e62346aa5e1affef210a');
INSERT INTO "sums" VALUES('file','','charles.local.db','9c50689e8185e5a79fd9077c14636405');
COMMIT;
```

Here is the code I try to run on python3.5 interactive shell:

```
from pony.orm import *
db = Database()
class File(db.Entity) :
    _table_ = 'sums'
    t = Required(str)
    path = Required(bytes)
    name = Required(bytes)
    sum = Required(str)
    PrimaryKey(path,name)
db.bind('sqlite','/some/edited/path/test.db')
db.generate_mapping()

File.select().show()
```

And it fails like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 5149, in _fetch
    try: result = cache.query_results[query_key]
KeyError: (('f', 0, ()), (<pony.orm.ormtypes.SetType object at 0x7fd2d2701708>,), False, None, None, None, False, False, False, ())

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in show
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pony/utils/utils.py", line 75, in cut_traceback
    raise exc  # Set "pony.options.CUT_TRACEBACK = False" to see full traceback
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pony/utils/utils.py", line 60, in cut_traceback
    try: return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 5256, in show
    query._fetch().show(width)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 5155, in _fetch
    used_attrs=translator.get_used_attrs())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 3859, in _fetch_objects
    real_entity_subclass, pkval, avdict = entity._parse_row_(row, attr_offsets)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 3889, in _parse_row_
    avdict[attr] = attr.parse_value(row, offsets)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 1922, in parse_value
    val = attr.validate(row[offset], None, attr.entity, from_db=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 2218, in validate
    val = Attribute.validate(attr, val, obj, entity, from_db)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 1894, in validate
    if from_db: return converter.sql2py(val)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pony/orm/dbapiprovider.py", line 619, in sql2py
    if not isinstance(val, buffer): val = buffer(val)
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

Am I using this wrong, or is this a bug ? I don't mind go filing a bug, but it's the first time I'm using this orm, so I thought it might be better to check first ...

Comment: Why are you using blobs for those columns in the first place?

Comment: I feared this question would come... I think it's off topic to answer, but for the sake of curiosity: Files names and paths from a variety of machines with different OS and different locales... I ran into unicode problems at harvest time with strings, just needed to shove the data some place for later processing. The point is: I'm stuck with it, and I could convert it in sqlite3, or avoid using pony (have tried both, that works thanks), but for the sake of the exercise with pony, I wanted to extract the blobs....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite has a (mis)feature, which allows a column to store an arbitrary value disregarding the column type. Instead of rigid data type, each SQLite column has an affinity, while each value has a storage class which can be different within the same column. For example, you can store text value inside an integer column, and vice versa. See [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) for more information.

The reason for the error is that the table contains values of "wrong" type in its BLOB columns. Correct SQLite binary literal [looks](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) like `x'abcdef'`. The `INSERT` commands that you use insert UTF8 strings instead.

This problem was somewhat fixed in the [latest version of Pony](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony) which you can take from GitHub. Now if Pony receives a string value from a BLOB column it just keep that value without throwing an exception.

If you populate the table with Pony, it will writes BLOB data as a correct binary values, so it can read them later without any problem.

Comment: ok so in essence I was trying to read a blob that was not a blob. For the sake of my exercise I converted the column to actual blobs and it worked. thanks !